# Using Flex (the lexical analizer) on OS X

Tags: macos, flex-lexer

I've got a file, test.lex, which I run through as

```
$ flex test.lex
```

That gives me lex.yy.c, which I try to compile with:

```
$ gcc lex.yy.c -lfl
```

This gives me the error ld: library not found for -lfl.  I know the Flex specification is correct and lex.yy.c compiles fine on a Linux machine.  Any suggestions?

Edit: I'm using the flex supplied by Apple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some systems make libfl a separate package from flex, as it is rarely needed.  The libfl library just contains two functions:

```
int main() {
    while (yylex());
    return 0;
}

int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}
```

Normally you'll want your own `main` function rather than the one from `libfl`, and defining `yywrap` yourself is trivial.  Alternately, you can use `%option noyywrap` and not need it at all.

In your case, try just getting rid of the `-lfl` option.  If you get an error about `yywrap`, add
`%option noyywrap` to the first section of your `test.lex` file.

Comment: Interesting.  I had to both add %option noyywrap to test.lex and leave off -lfl as one would expect, but I wonder why OS X couldn't find libfl?

Comment: probably because you don't have it installed.

Comment: I assumed that since I have the flex binary, I have libfl.  What I do have is libl.a, which seems to provide the same functionality.  I'm using the flex supplied by Apple.

Answer (score 4):

old topic but accepted answer did not help me.
so I'm adding this answer.

on macos use -ll (as in "library lex").
valid for macos 10.14 mojave.

also as @Chris Dodd said you can get rid of this dependency by specifying `%option noyywrap` in `.l` file and providing own `main` routine `.y` file.