# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfl

Tags: ubuntu, flex-lexer

I wrote `gcc lex.yy.c -o ornek -lfl` in command line. Then I get an error as follows:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37971/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lfl

Comment: Hiw did you install flex? (And are you really using Ubuntu?) Regardless, there is good information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064096/using-flex-the-lexical-analizer-on-os-x/26064848

Comment: @rici I’m using linux mint. I installed writing like sudo apt -get install flex byacc in command line

Answer (score 4):

You need to separately install `libfl-dev` in order to have the `fl` library.

But you probably don't need that library. It only provides two things, neither of which is particularly useful:

- A do-nothing definition of `yywrap`. Instead if using this, avoid the need by placing

  ```
  %option noyywrap
  ```

  in the first section of your flex file.
- A definition of `main` which just calls `yylex` repeatedly. Normally, you will want to write a more interesting `main` function. But if you want to duplicate the default provided in `-lfl`, it looks basically like this:

  ```
  int main(void) {
    while(yylex()) { }
    return 0;
  }
  ```